# Issue with font rendering inside applications

Tags: fonts, browser

My current settings are:

- antialiasing: none
- hinting: full

This has changed the appearance of fonts in menus, titlebars and most apps (including Skype, system settings, Unity Tweak Tool, etc.) However, fonts on websites in Chrome and Firefox are still rendering fonts as *antialiased.

Sorry if this has been posted before. All I've been able to find is threads/questions about fonts being rendered poorly, but that isn't my issue.

[Here](https://i.imgur.com/M01LMAk.png) is an example of the issue I'm having.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try Fix it through Unity Tweak Tool.

[image]

Click **Restore defaults** and voila! 
Hope it Help.

Comment: That's not what I want, though. Sorry if it wasn't clear. I want to have antialiasing off everywhere, not just in system apps/titlebars/etc. I'd like it to be off inside the browser as well. As in, I'd like the text on websites to be rendered as aliased, rather than antialiased.